# Comparing linear models between categories after different transformations

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Suppose I have a predictor variable $X$ split into two categories $X_a$ and $X_b$, and a response variable $Y$. I wish to perform linear regression but need to transform both $X_a$ and $X_b$ as to be linear with respect to $Y$.

I chose the Box-Cox transform, however I found the optimal parameters (which minimize the residual errors) to be $\lambda_a=3.5$ and $\lambda_b=0$ ($\log$ transform). That is, I find the maximal correlation coefficients for
$$\begin{cases}Y\sim b_0+b_1\cdot\text{BC}(X_a,\lambda=3.5)\\Y\sim b_0+b_1\cdot\text{BC}(X_b,\lambda=0)\end{cases}$$
where $\text{BC}$ denotes Box-Cox transform. Is this proper to do for different $\lambda$? Or should I use the same $\lambda$ for both transformations? If so, what $\lambda$ should I choose? Any help is appreciated.

For reference Box Cox transform is defined
$$\text{BC}(x,\lambda)=\frac{x^\lambda-1}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Could you expand a little on what your ultimate goal is? Is the predictor variable $X$ continuous? How and why do you split it into two groups?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Well, more specifically I have a set of geographical regions and each one has a proportion of two groups (usually adding up to 90%) along with an associated value $Y$. I am interested how the proportions of the two groups correlate with the variable $Y$, and in finding that correlation I use the Box Cox transform. So it is a correlation between proportion of group $A$ and the variable $Y$, and same for group $B$. The issue is when linearizing my data I use different parameters for the two groups. The proportions continuous and $Y$ is a count.

Comment: Thanks (I'd suggest adding these explanations to your question too). If $Y$ is a count, have you thought about fitting a Poisson regression model? Maybe the transformation isn't even needed.